# How to "escape" a comma in a PHP argument value so it doesn't separate them into multiple arguments

Tags: php

I have a PHP Method like so that accepts arguments and builds a radio button group

```
protected function radio($jsfunction='') {
    $radioElements = func_get_args();
    ...
}
```

I want a build a simple radio group with two arguments. Unfortunately, one element of the group includes commas, which seems to get interpreted as additional arguments. For example:

```
 radio("confirmSelection(this)","Option1","Option2,3,4")
```

This is creating 4 entries in the radioElements array above. Is there some way I can escape the commas within the (intended) 2nd argument so it will interpret "Option2,3,4" as one argument instead of 3?

Comment: If you run `var_dump($radioElements);` in the above code, you will only get an array with 3 items. Can you please take another look at your code and decipher what the issue may be? Perhaps in the code that actually "creates the `radioElement` entries".

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for looking into this. You're right, it's actually a regular expression somewhere else in the code that's responsible for parsing through the arguments in that way. Should I delete the question myself? I will, just don't want to do anything to tarnish my reputation/standing.

Comment: Deleting a question does not hurt your reputation (you would lose any reputation gained from the question). Usually the right scenario here would be to update the question with the newly-found issue (at that point, we would re-open the question and you can even answer your own question if you solved the regular expression issue). However, as of now (since there is an answer with upvotes and an accepted answer) you cannot delete your question. No worries, I do not believe you are penalized for having a question put on hold..at least if it does not become a permanent thing :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that:

```
function foo ($js = '') {
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}

foo('a', 'b', 'c,d,e');

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "c,d,e"
}
```

3 arguments, 3 array entries in what gets returned from func_get_args().

You'll have to show exactly what you're doing to get the `c,d,e` thing split up.